# Why does the first access time for ConcurrentDictionary take so much longer than consequent accesses?

Tags: c#, dictionary, data-structures, concurrency, concurrentdictionary

I had an idea to try out the access times of common data structures, one being `Dictionary`. As such, I made a small program to test how many ticks it takes to access the data as opposed to directly computing the values (I know, this is not useful, just an experiment).

However, I stumbled on an interesting issue. The first time I access the `ConcurrentDictionary`, the `ElapsedTicks` is always much higher than the consequent access times.

**Why is this the case?**

Screenshots:

[image: Try 1] [image: Try 2] [image: Try 3]

Code:

```cs
public static void Main() {
    var aLimit = 1000;
    var bLimit = aLimit;

    var precomputed = new ConcurrentDictionary<Tuple<int, int>, int>();
    Parallel.For(0, aLimit, a => {
        Parallel.For(0, bLimit, b => {
            while (!precomputed.TryAdd(new Tuple<int, int>(a, b), a * b));
        });
    });

    Console.Write("Press enter to begin.");
    Console.ReadLine();
    var repeats = 5;
    var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    var random = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < repeats; ++i) {
        stopwatch.Reset();
        var v1 = random.Next(0, aLimit);
        var v2 = random.Next(0, bLimit);

        // precomputed
        stopwatch.Start();
        var precomputedResult = precomputed[new Tuple<int, int>(v1, v2)];
        stopwatch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine($"[{i}] V: {precomputedResult} | Precomp: {stopwatch.ElapsedTicks}");

        stopwatch.Reset();

        // actual
        stopwatch.Start();
        var actualResult = v1 * v2;
        stopwatch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine($"[{i}] V: {actualResult} | Actual: {stopwatch.ElapsedTicks}");
    }
}
```

Comment: I would assume that’s when the dictionary accessor gets JITed, i.e. gets compiled by the JIT from IL code to native code.

Comment: might, be the jitter creating initializing ConcurrentDictionary<Tuple<int, int>, int>

Answer (score 2):

I would say the main reason for this behavior is JIT compilation of indexer method. If you run your code multiple times, for example wrapping whole code into another `for` cycle - you will see that the subsequent "first" accesses will have around the same measurements. On my machine I have next outputs for 1st iterations in 4 cycles:

```
[0] V: 912780 | Precomp: 6200
[0] V: 912780 | Actual: 1
[0] V: 508870 | Precomp: 78
[0] V: 508870 | Actual: 0
[0] V: 195570 | Precomp: 57
[0] V: 195570 | Actual: 5
[0] V: 67643 | Precomp: 156
[0] V: 67643 | Actual: 1
[0] V: 418966 | Precomp: 63
[0] V: 418966 | Actual: 1
```

Also if you are interested in microbenchmarking I would recommend using [BenchmarkDotNet](https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet), which handles a lot of stuff, like timer resolutions, warm ups and so on.